# mongodb: How to model a pie (the whole to a small collection of parts)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, data-modeling

### The Problem

I need to model a document which is defined as the "whole" to a small, fixed collection of "parts", where both the whole and its parts are queryable.

A sliced pie is a good example of the model I need.  Further describing the domain:

- pie:slice has a 1:many (1-10) relationship.  Each slice belongs to only one pie, and each pie has 1-10 slices.
- For this example, assume that the pie is sliced at creation, and the number of slices *does not change*.
- A pie is *always* queried with its slices.  The opposite is not necessarily true, but a queried slice will need access to metadata about the pie
- For the example, assume that "weight" is the only property of a slice. The metadata shared by all slices is much larger than that for each slice.  All slices have the same baker, filling, crust, kitchen, and so on.  To *not* have to duplicate all data to each slice would be ideal.
- Both slices and pies must be efficiently queryable and sortable by attributes of the whole pie, or attributes of the slices.  Examples:

  - Find all pies with exactly 2 slices
  - Find all pies with a slice weighing > 10oz
  - Find all slices with type "cherry"
  - Find the 5 heaviest slices across all pies

---

### The Question:

Given the above points, how would one model a `pie` and its `slices` to be efficiently queryable (and if possible, efficiently stored)?

If this is obvious, please answer.  Read on for the two approaches I've tried so far and why neither are satisfactory.

---

### What I've tried:

**1. Embedding**

Embedding parts inside of the whole [seemed to be the natural choice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#embedding).

```
Pie {
  type: String, // `type` and other shared attrs are defined on Pie
  slices: [{
    _id: ObjectId
    weight: Number
  }]
}
```

With this I can query for pies by type, weight, slice weight, and I can query for individual cherry pie slices via `aggregate`, `unzip`, and `project`.

**The problem** lies in how to **sort and query** on individual slices.  For example, what if I needed to retrieve the 5 heaviest slices from *all* pies (as described in the problem above).  I this is possible to do with aggregation, I don't know how.

---

**2. Separate Collections**

After giving up on my first schema I fell back to using two separate collections, joined by a reference id:

```
Pie {
  type: String // `type` and other shared attrs are defined on Pie ...
}

Slice {
  pie_id: ObjectId,
  type: String, // ... and duplicated to all slices
  weight: Number
}
```

This solves my query problem, but introduces a few more.  Here just `type` is duplicated.  In my real application this is far worse, to the point where my analog to `Slice` is probably 90% duplicate data.

The other problem is that now whenever I want to query for pies, I have to query again for all the slices.  Furtermore making the pie is no longer an atomic operation, but a batch of separate inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I went with, though perhaps not the only or best answer, was to denormalize the data on both sides of the relationship.

Essentially, the `slices` are embedded in their entiredy within `pie` document, ***and*** the slices exist in their own collection complete with duplicated `pie` metadata.  In this way the pie and its slices can be independently queried, without any secondary queries required.

Is 2-way duplication storage efficient?  Probably not, but then again storage is not an issue here.

Does this make updating the docs more complicated and multiple operations?  Yes, but updates will happen far, far less than reads, which are much more important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/ 
In particular, "Model Tree Structures with Child References" seems just what you are looking for. You can store only the data most specific to a particular slice in the slice document (such as slice weight), and everything else in the Pie document.

Comment: I have seen this page actually.  It feels similar to what I'm doing in example #2 above, and seems like it suffers from the same problem.  For example, how would I efficiently query both pies and slices by type, without duplicating type onto both documents?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a structure like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5112d747819e326e6c37e1e3"),
    "pie" : {
        "type" : "cherry",
        "weight" : 500,
        "slices" : [
            {
                "slice_id" : ObjectId("5112d747819e326e6c37e1e1"),
                "type" : "square",
                "weight" : 75
            },
            {
                "slice_id" : ObjectId("5112d747819e326e6c37e1e2"),
                "type" : "triangle",
                "weight" : 75
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You could then use $unwind and $sort like:

```
db.q14735834.aggregate({$unwind: "$pie.slices"}, {$sort: {"pie.slices.weight":-1}}, {$limit:10})
```

And further combinations of $group and other aggregation framework operators to manipulate the data.

Aside from the tutorial referenced by [Alptigin Jalayr] the aggregation framework docs may be of use: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: I make use of aggregation a lot actually.  Very useful.  I guess what I'm concerned about here is how well aggregation would perform with a query as you suggest on a very large dataset.  As essentially we're unwinding the entire collection to sort by weight here.

Comment: It depends…on how large the dataset is.  There are some limits you may run into (32Mb for sorts, 16Mb for BSON documents).  Can you do any filtering first, to select sizes that are larger than or smaller than some arbitrary value?

Comment: This is where I'm running into problems.  Say, continuing with the heaviest 10 slices example, that both the heaviest and lightest slices in the whole dataset are in the same pie.  How could you filter that?  It seems like for such a query you'd have to scan the whole collection.

Comment: Profiling this in the console with 20000 pies with 5 slices each, it already takes over a second.  `slices.weight` is indexed but I don't think it's using it.  Same aggregate *without* the unwind runs 40ms.